# Google maps IOS:Recalculate Route In Direction of travelling

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I m using Google map For my IOS application.

I m able to calculate Route and draw polyline based on it from directions  API. The present direction api and my code is working well. But if user is not going to drawn route or going to wrong direction. I would like to recalculate route from the direction user is travelling not from the direction user is coming on. I m recalculating route for every 100 meters if not going to routhpath which is drawn.

It's calculating route correctly but in the opposite direction i m travelling on. So it should detect the direction i'm going on a road and not the backwards direction from which i m coming.

Here is code snippet. I written in delegate didUpdateToLocations:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

if (aLocationDistanceLoc  ==  Nil) {
    aLocationDistanceLoc=[[CLLocation alloc]init];
    aLocationDistanceLoc=newLocation;
}
else
{
    CLLocationDistance distance1 = [aLocationDistanceLoc distanceFromLocation:newLocation];
    if (distance1 > 100) {
        aLocationDistanceLoc=newLocation;
        if (GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance(newLocation.coordinate, routesPath, YES, 10)) {
        }
        else
        {
            flagForRouteRecalculateActive=YES;

            [self callApiForNavigation:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude] destinationPoint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",currentLatDropoff ,currentLongDropoff ]];
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my Directions API call:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true&mode=driving",[[arrayStart objectAtIndex:0] floatValue],[[arrayStart objectAtIndex:1] floatValue],[[arrayDestination objectAtIndex:0] floatValue],[[arrayDestination objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]]
```

Here is the Video demonstration of problem. You'll see as i moving in direction the route is recalculating but its recalculate from backward direction. I need to recalculate from front in the direction i m going.

[video of actual Issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6egb0cag3yt9ms/recalculateRoute.mov?dl=0)

Comment: The Directions API is based on the `origin` and `destination` coordinates, if you have a correct `destination` coordinate, the API should give you a correct route. So what `origin` and `destination` coordinates you use in your API request? You can also set the `alternatives` parameter to `true` to get more alternative routes from the API response. Also, the Directions API is not based on the user's current heading, if the user is heading to north, the route does not necessary to start from north. In addition, you might want to specify some `waypoints` in the request.

Comment: thanks. But Google maps IOS application do the same and i need to implement the same. They did it from direction of travelling.

Comment: Do you have screenshot of what you trying to make?

Comment: Sure. I have edited my post please check the video link.

Comment: Have you tried to use `waypoints` in your request parameter? If a car heading to south, u can specify a waypoint in south, so the route might point to south.

Comment: yes I have already tried Waypoints. I have given waypoints of 5, 10 ,15 meters away from Direction of travelling. But it not works it creates from back ward.

Comment: Add "via:" after "&waypoints=" word,
like this:
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=sydney,au&destination=perth,au&waypoints=via:-37.81223%2C144.96254%7C-34.92788%2C138.60008&key=YOUR_API_KEY